# set another node_modules path to my grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, maven, gruntjs

I m using the [Frontend Maven Plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) with Grunt v0.4.5. My configuration worked, when the node_modules folder is in the same folder as package.json and Gruntfile.js. But now i have to put the node_modules folder in a subfolder, sth. like:

```
-Gruntfile.js
-package.json
-test/
 --node_modules
```

When I run the script I get this error message, while it does the 'grunt' command:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Develop\mvn-proj\my-app\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt'
```

Where or how can I set the path of the node_modules folder?

edit: FYI npm is used with a local install in the folder.

Comment: have you read this ? http://rusticode.com/2012/09/17/error-cannot-find-module-express/

Comment: No not now, but as i mention in my 'edit': node, npm,... are no global variables.

Comment: why do you need to place it in subfolder?

Comment: because it has to be installed in the maven target folder ;)